# Data types in Java

Tags: types, literals

```
class Test
{
      public  static void main(String[] args)
      {
              double a= 0786;
              System.out.println(a);

 
      }
}
```

//Why does double a=0786 gives error (integer number too large) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integer literal with a leading 0 is an [*octal* literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-OctalIntegerLiteral), and 8 isn't a valid digit within octal literals.

If you actually want a value of 786 decimal, just remove the leading 0:

```java
double a = 786;
```

Comment: but this is an integer literal right? so integer literal can be octal, hexadecimal, decimal

Comment: @Saksam: Um yes, I've said it's an octal literal (because it starts with a 0). But an octal literal isn't allowed to include the digit 8. I'm genuinely unclear what the point of confusion is. If you think it's a decimal literal, then the problem is the leading 0 which makes it an octal literal. If you agree it's an octal literal, what value to you expect the 8 within it to have?

Comment: okk now I get it since it is starting with 0 it must be octal but 8 is not included in octal so it gives an error.Am I right?

Comment: @Saksam: Yes, exactly.